# React Native Community Checkbox onValueChange Not Working

Tags: javascript, react-native

The @react-native-community/checkbox I'm using to allow the user to select subject only calls the onValueChange once. So you can check it but you can't uncheck it.

I tested this by doing a console.log on every call to the function, it only prints once. I also log the subjects state before and after, it changes as expected and the selected value that is used on the Checkbox value prop is updated.

I also use a Checkbox on a different screen and it works perfectly, so I don't think I have an installation issue.

The Checkbox Component:

```
<>
  <NKCard>
    <Text style={styles.heading}>Module 1</Text>
    {subjects
      .filter(subject => subject.Module === '1')
      .map(subject => {
        return (
          <View key={subject.id} style={styles.subject}>
          <Checkbox
            disabled={subject.disabled}
            value={subject.selected}
            onValueChange={() => {
              handleSubjectSelect(subject.id);
            }}
            tintColors={{true: '#36b254', false: '#36b254'}}
          />
          <Text style={styles.subjectTitle}>{subject.Title}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    })}
  </NKCard>
</>
```

The handleSubjectSelect Function:

```
const handleSubjectSelect = id => {
  console.log('change');
  setSubjects(currentSubjects => {
    console.log(currentSubjects);
    currentSubjects.forEach(subject => {
      if (subject.id === id) {
        subject.selected = !subject.selected;
        console.log('update');
      }
    });
    console.log(currentSubjects);

    return currentSubjects;
  });
};
```

Console Logs:

```
[Sun May 24 2020 22:31:55.883]  LOG      change

[Sun May 24 2020 22:31:55.885]  LOG      [{"Grade": "1", "Module": "1", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "15", "selected": 
false}, {"Grade": "1", "Module": "2", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "16", "selected": false}, {"Grade": "1", "Module": "3", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "17", "selected": false}, {"Grade": "1", "Module": "4", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "18", "selected": false}]

[Sun May 24 2020 22:31:55.891]  LOG      update

[Sun May 24 2020 22:31:55.898]  LOG      [{"Grade": "1", "Module": "1", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "15", "selected": 
true}, {"Grade": "1", "Module": "2", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "16", "selected": false}, {"Grade": "1", "Module": "3", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "17", "selected": false}, {"Grade": "1", "Module": "4", "Status": "active", "Title": "Math", "disabled": false, "id": "18", "selected": false}]
```

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow Dominic! Instead of using screenshot, can you copy/paste the code, logs, etc in text format please? For more information about screenshots, you can read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @jmaitrehenry I've changed it as requested.

Answer (score -2):

Found my mistake.

I changed the selected value of the object directly on currentSubjects in the handleSubjectSelect function. I fixed it by making a new duplicate of the currentSubjects and changing the object inside it, then returning newSubjects.

Solution:

```
const handleSubjectSelect = id => {
  console.log('change');
  setSubjects(currentSubjects => {
    console.log(currentSubjects);

    const newSubjects = [...currentSubjects];

    newSubjects.forEach(subject => {
      if (subject.id === id) {
        subject.selected = !subject.selected;
        console.log('update');
      }
    });
    console.log(newSubjects);

    return newSubjects;
  });
};
```